# Excel find text if contained in lookup table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

i have following table

[image]

I need an Excel formula in column A for all values in column B. the formula should look for all values in column 'lookup table' one by one and find if the value (for example 'aaa') is contained column 'lookup value'. for example in this case (aaa) it is in B2 and B6.
The following should be the result

[image]

will appreciate your help. i looked for vlookup and but normally the formula is used for value in column C. in my case i need for column B.

best regards
rnv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ISNUMBER(MATCH()):

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&$C$2:$C$4&"*",B2,0))),"x","")
```

[image]

Using ISNUMBER(SEARCH())

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$4,B2))),"x","")
```

[image]

With Office 365 Dynamic BYROW, we can spill:

```
=BYROW(B2:B6,LAMBDA(a,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$4,a))),"x","")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Check For Partial Matches Using `TEXTSPLIT`

[image]

```
=LET(v,B2:B6,l,C2:C4,y,"x",n,"",b,"",
    vLen,LEN(v),sLen,LEN(TEXTSPLIT(v,l)),
IF(vLen=0,b,IF(vLen>sLen,y,n)))
```

Comment: Creative approach

Answer (score 1):

Not really the question, but likely what you're after:

```
=LET(value,  B2:B5,
     table,  C2:C4,
FILTER(value,
       MMULT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TOROW(table),value))),
             SEQUENCE(ROWS(table),,,0))))
```

This will list the values that meet the conditions only.

Else you can not use the filter, but use IF instead:

```
=LET(value,  B2:B5,
     table,  C2:C4,
IF(MMULT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TOROW(table),value))),SEQUENCE(ROWS(table),,,0)),
   "x",
   ""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using <kbd>ISTEXT( )</kbd> & <kbd>TEXTBEFORE( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula in cell `A2`

```
=IF(ISTEXT(TEXTBEFORE(B2:B6,C2:C4)),"x","")
```

---

[image]

---

Comment: That's it. Game over.